# Rails timezone is wrong when shown

Tags: ruby-on-rails, timezone

I have a problem when showing a datetime object from the database. The time is correctly set in when storing the object, but when it is fetched from db and shown to user it is shown in UTC

environment.rb

```
config.time_zone = 'Copenhagen'
```

This is what is saved using `Time.now` or `Time.zone.now`

**2010-07-08 13:59:50 +0200**

This is what is shown to the user when using the html helper `<%=h ff.date_registered %>`
**2010-07-08 11:59:50 UTC**

Comment: Did you ever figure out the answer to this..

Comment: No, i still have this problem

Comment: Check out this question: it may help you out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4362663/timezone-with-rails-3

Comment: @AaronWeiker put your comment as a question and get a checkmark. That question you refered to answers my question

Answer (score 1):

Try Time.current. Time.now is returned in UTC -5 always. ActiveRecord instructs Time.current based on your config.time_zone. See this github issue for more information, https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/3128#issuecomment-2195751