# Timezone with rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, timezone

I have pretty common issue but for some reason i have tried all the suggestions on the web and none seem to work.

I have set the Timezone in config to 'EST'

```
config.time_zone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'
```

But when the time is shown on the the screen, it continues to show the UTC time that is stored in the DB. I tried the debugger and here is the output

```
(rdb:1) Time.zone 
#<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x1061f4760 @utc_offset=nil, @current_period=nil, @name="Eastern Time (US & Canada)", @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::TimezoneProxy: America/New_York>>
(rdb:1) Order.first.placed_at
Fri Jan 01 15:00:00 UTC 2010
```

Update: 
Here is another user who has the same question
[Rails timezone is wrong when shown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3203304/rails-timezone-is-wrong-when-shown)

Comment: More on Timezones: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Try `in_time_zone`. For example

```
>> Time.now
=> Sun Dec 05 21:34:45 -0500 2010
>> Time.zone
=> #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x1033d97b8 @name="Pacific Time (US & Canada)", @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone: America/Los_Angeles>, @utc_offset=-28800, @current_period=nil>
>> Time.now.in_time_zone
=> Sun, 05 Dec 2010 18:34:54 PST -08:00
```

In your case, you want `Order.first.placed_at.in_time_zone`.

Comment: But I thought setting the timezone in the config would automatically instruct activerecord to retrieve in local timezone.. http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2008/1/25/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-easier-timezones

Comment: In my experience, I had to explicitly tell the view to use the local timezone (instead of UTC). Perhaps a better way exists.

Comment: or even `Time.zone.now`
this seems to return the same for me (rails 3.1) and reads slightly better I think

Comment: negative. The correct way to call it would be Time.current. I went through the same problem you had, use #current instead of #now to to get the time for the given time zone.

Answer (score 11):

If you want to **set a different time zone for different users of your app**, make sure you use an around_filter as opposed to a before filter to change Time.zone.  Something to do with how Time.zone leaks over to other threads and thus other users may inheret a time zone that they shouldn't.  From this blog post: http://ilikestuffblog.com/2011/02/03/how-to-set-a-time-zone-for-each-request-in-rails/

in application_controller.rb:

```
around_filter :set_time_zone

private

def set_time_zone
  old_time_zone = Time.zone
  Time.zone = current_user.time_zone if logged_in?
  yield
ensure
  Time.zone = old_time_zone
end
```

I also found it helpful to use the **time_zone_select** form helper method when allowing users to change their time zone.  If you called your field :time_zone, you would use it like:

```
f.time_zone_select(:time_zone)
```

And lastly, this looks pretty awesome.  **Auto detect and set time zone via javascript**.  Here's the rails gem to add to the asset pipeline: https://github.com/scottwater/detect_timezone_rails and accompanying blog post: http://www.scottw.com/automated-timezone-detection

Comment: perfect answer, if you ask me!!

Answer (score 2):

Check that your `ActiveRecord::Base.time_zone_aware_attributes` is true.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're describing is this bug - https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/6816