# Time zone selections/defaults - how to keep hidden in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, datetime, time, timezone

I'm having an issue with time zone.

I've put

```
config.time_zone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'
config.active_record.default_timezone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'
```

In my application.rb file, and for the most part it handles the time correctly - everywhere except for in a form.
For some reason, it shows the UTC time in the form, and you have to enter the time in UTC.  Everywhere else (including if I output the time right above the text field for debugging), it shows it in the correct local time, although it does still show the -0400, which I'd also like to hide.
Outputting the time on the page gives me: "2012-04-07 02:35:00 -0400"
But in the form, it shows up as "2012-04-07 06:35:00.000000"

Any thoughts on why it is showing differently in the form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried `Time.now.in_time_zone` instead of just `Time.now`, see this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4362663/timezone-with-rails-3)