# How to fix the time difference between javascript ( full calendar ) and rails?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, fullcalendar

I'm using full calendar jquery plugin for creating a timetable with the following code

```
$("#calendar").fullCalendar {
 defaultView: 'agendaWeek'
 hiddenDays: [0]
 axisFormat: 'HH:mm'
 minTime: '8:00'
 maxTime: '22:00'
 selectable: true
 agenda: 'h:mm{ - h:mm}'
 eventColor: '#00CCFF'
 eventBackgroundColor: '#00CCFF'
 defaultEventMinutes: 60
 editable: true
 DurationEditable: true
 allDayDefault: false
 droppable: true
 columnFormat:
   week: 'ddd'
 eventResize: (event,dayDelta,minuteDelta,revertFunc) ->
   alert event
 eventDrop: (event,dayDelta,minuteDelta,allDay,revertFunc) ->
   $.ajax
     url: "/events/#{event.id}"
     type: 'PATCH'
     data:
       'event':
         'start' : event.start
         'dayDelta' : dayDelta
         'minuteDelta' : minuteDelta
     success: (data) ->
 drop: (date, allDay, jsEvent, ui) ->
   copiedEventObject = {}
   copiedEventObject.start = date
   copiedEventObject.title = $(this).text()
   copiedEventObject.data_id = $(this).attr 'data-id'
   copiedEventObject.data_type = $(this).attr 'data-type'
   copiedEventObject.slotMinutes = Number($(this).attr('data-duration')) * 60
   copiedEventObject.allDay = allDay
   $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', copiedEventObject, true);
   $(this).hide()
   $.post '/events', { 'event' : { 'title' : copiedEventObject.title, 'start' : copiedEventObject.start, 'data_id' : copiedEventObject.data_id, 'data_type' : copiedEventObject.data_type } }, (data) ->

 eventSources: [ "/events/?courses=#{courses}" ]
 header: {
   left: '',
   center: '',
   right: ''
 }
}
timeFormat: 'H(:mm)'
```

In my controller I have to add 5 hours and 30 minutes to the time I get from javascript.

```
def create
case params[:event][:data_type]
when 'lecture'
  parent = Lecture.find(params[:event][:data_id])
when 'tutorial'
  parent = Tutorial.find(params[:event][:data_id])
when 'lab'
  parent = Lab.find(params[:event][:data_id])
end
params[:event][:start] = DateTime.parse(params[:event][:start]) + 5.hours + 30.minutes
event = parent.create_event(event_params)
if event then parent.update_attribute(:scheduled,true) end
render nothing: true
end
```

If I dont do this the event when rendered on the calendar appears to be 5 hours and 30 minutes behind the time where I dropped it.
Why is the problem cropping up.please help

Comment: RoR uses the server time, Javascript uses the client computers time, there's no guarantee that they are the same. Then there's local times etc. If you need the times to match, get the servertime and use that in both.

Comment: Try setting your timezone in the environment.rb in config? Also, this page might help you [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4362663/timezone-with-rails-3)

Comment: @adeneo Can you please explain this part "If you need the times to match, get the servertime and use that in both.". The date/time is being generated dynamically based on what part of the calendar I drop the event on.